# Mark Checkbox if text box has text

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, checkbox, textbox

I have a checkboxfor and a textboxfor.  If a user enters text into the textboxfor I would like the corresponding checkboxfor to be automatically checked for the user.  With the option of course to un-check it if they change their mind.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.FirstPledge)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstPledgeText, new { @class = "textBoxSize" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may listen to the `keyup` event, check the content in textbox is valid and set the `checked` property of the checkbox to `true`.

Here is the code to do so using jQuery.

```
$(function () {
    $("#FirstPledgeText").keyup(function () {
        if($.trim($(this).val())!=="")
        {
            $("#FirstPledge").prop("checked", true);
        }
    });   
})
```

If you want to uncheck the checkbox when the textbox is empty, add an else part to the if condition and set `false` for the `checked` property.

You can do the same in vanilla JavaScript as well if you prefer that.